# div not hiding when radio button clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a form with radio buttons that show a different question depending on the selection made in the first question.

When an option is selected in the first question, the second question shows fine. But when you change the answer in the first question, the second question doesn't hide.

For Example:
you have a radio button with two options:
* Car
* Bike

When you click "Car" the second question about the car shows up. But when a user made a mistake and changes the radio button to "Bike". The second question about the bike shows, but the one about the Car doesn't hide and both are showing.

```js
function ShowCar() {
  document.getElementById('DivCar').style.display = "";
  document.getElementById('IpCar').disabled = false;

  document.getElementById('DivBike').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('IpBike').disabled = true;
}

function ShowBike() {
  document.getElementById('DivBike').style.display = "";
  document.getElementById('IpBike').disabled = false;

  document.getElementById('DivCar').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('IpCar').disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<div id="prod">
  <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
      <td>Car or Bike?</td>
      <td>
        <form>
          <input type="radio" name="product" id="Car" value="Car" onChange="ShowCar()" /> Car<br>
          <input type="radio" name="product" id="Bike" value="Bike" onChange="ShowBike()" /> Bike<br>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<br />
<div id="DivCar" style="display:none">
  <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
      <td>What type of car is it?</td>
      <td>
        <form>
          <input type="radio" name="IpCar" value="Car_Sedan"> Sedan<br>
          <input type="radio" name="IpCar" value="Car_Truck"> Truck<br>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<br />
<div id="DivBike" style="display:none">
  <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
      <td>What type of bike is it?</td>
      <td>
        <form>
          <input type="radio" name="IpBike" value="Bike_Sports"> Sports<br>
          <input type="radio" name="IpBike" value="Bike_Chopper"> Chopper<br>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<br />
```

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors? you may have to give `id`s to individual radio inputs https://jsfiddle.net/x2nbv7rd/

Answer (score 3):

Your show/hide approach is OK but setting/removing the `disabled` attribute is arising the problem.

You are trying to select the HTML element by `ID` (IpBike, IpCar) which is no more exist. You have radio input field who's name are `IpBike, IpCar`.

So instead of `getElementById` you can use `querySelectorAll()`

**Example code:**

```js
function ShowCar()
{
    document.getElementById('DivCar').style.display = "";
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="IpCar"]')).forEach(i => i.removeAttribute('disabled'));

    document.getElementById('DivBike').style.display = "none";
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="IpBike"]')).forEach(i => i.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled'));

}

function ShowBike()
{
    document.getElementById('DivBike').style.display = "";
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="IpBike"]')).forEach(i => i.removeAttribute('disabled'));

    document.getElementById('DivCar').style.display = "none";
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="IpCar"]')).forEach(i => i.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled'));
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="prod">
    <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <td>Car or Bike?</td>
            <td><form>
                <input type="radio" name="product" id="Car" value="Car" onChange="ShowCar()" /> Car<br>
                <input type="radio" name="product" id="Bike" value="Bike" onChange="ShowBike()" /> Bike<br>
            </form></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<br />
<div id="DivCar" style="display:none">
    <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <td>What type of car is it?</td>
            <td><form>
                <input type="radio" name="IpCar" value="Car_Sedan"> Sedan<br>
                <input type="radio" name="IpCar" value="Car_Truck"> Truck<br>
            </form></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<br />
<div id="DivBike" style="display:none">
    <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <td>What type of bike is it?</td>
            <td><form>
                <input type="radio" name="IpBike" value="Bike_Sports"> Sports<br>
                <input type="radio" name="IpBike" value="Bike_Chopper"> Chopper<br>
            </form></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to show one selection at a time then you don't need to do extra. Just hide bike when car is click and hide car if bike is clicked. And your trying to disable the property using wrong selector.

```
document.getElementById('IpBike').disabled = true;
```

should be

```
document.getElementById('Bike').disabled = true;
```

and

```
document.getElementById('IpCar').disabled = true;
```

should be

```
document.getElementById('Car').disabled = true;
```

Try following:

```html
<body>
<div id="prod">
  <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
      <td>Car or Bike?</td>
      <td><form>
        <input type="radio" name="product" id="Car" value="Car" onChange="ShowCar()" /> Car<br>
        <input type="radio" name="product" id="Bike" value="Bike" onChange="ShowBike()" /> Bike<br>
      </form></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<br />
<div id="DivCar" style="display:none">
  <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
      <td>What type of car is it?</td>
      <td><form>
        <input type="radio" name="IpCar" value="Car_Sedan"> Sedan<br>
        <input type="radio" name="IpCar" value="Car_Truck"> Truck<br>
      </form></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<br />
<div id="DivBike" style="display:none">
    <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
      <tr>
        <td>What type of bike is it?</td>
        <td><form>
          <input type="radio" name="IpBike" value="Bike_Sports"> Sports<br>
          <input type="radio" name="IpBike" value="Bike_Chopper"> Chopper<br>
        </form></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <br />
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

  function ShowCar()
  {
    document.getElementById('DivCar').style.display = "";
    document.getElementById('DivBike').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('Bike').disabled = true;// Use this line if you want to disable bike selection. Otherwise remove this line.
  }

  function ShowBike()
  {
    document.getElementById('DivBike').style.display = "";
    document.getElementById('DivCar').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('Car').disabled = true;// Use this line if you want to disable car selection. Otherwise remove this line.
  }

</script>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Just to add to this.  The reason it wasn't working was because of the lines with .disabled = true | false.  Disabled is not a valid property/field on a DOM Element Object.

Comment: @AndrewBone added few more explanation.

Comment: @TonyAbrams yes your are right. Included in my answer. As OP trying to disable the property with wrong selector.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried so many things, but I wasn't looking in the right places!

Answer (score 0):

```
function ShowCar() {
```

document.getElementById('DivCar').style.display = "";

document.getElementById('DivBike').style.display = "none";
}

function ShowBike() {
  document.getElementById('DivBike').style.display = "";

document.getElementById('DivCar').style.display = "none";
}